# app crashed when I launch another activity after a countdown of 3 sec

Tags: java, android, parsing, crash

This is my MainActivity.java

> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView (R.layout.activity_main2);
>     CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer (3000,1000) {
>         @Override
>         public void onTick(long l) {
>
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onFinish() {
>             startActivity (new Intent (MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
>         }
>     }.start ();
> } }
> ```

Here is my Main2Activity.java

> public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
>
> ```
> public static Button button;
> public static TextView temp;
> public static TextView cityname;
> public static TextView time;
> public static EditText written;
> public static ImageView imageView;
> RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
>     button = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button);
>     temp = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.temp);
>     cityname = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.cityname);
>     time = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.time);
>     relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById (R.id.relative);
>     written = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText);
>     imageView = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.imageView);
>     button.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view) {
>             try {
>                 if(written.getText ().toString ().isEmpty () || written.getText ().toString ().equals ("")){
>                     Toast.makeText (Main2Activity.this, "Enter your City name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
>                 }else {
>                     time.setAlpha (0f);
>                     temp.setAlpha (0f);
>                     cityname.setAlpha (0f);
>                     Parsing parsing = new Parsing ();
>                     parsing.execute ();
>                     written.setText("");
>                 }
>             }catch (Exception e){
>
>             }
>         }
>     });
> } }
> ```

This app crashed when I press the button, without anything the app crashes.

Comment: Please post full logcat error.

Comment: Check the layout file
you have declared `R.layout.activity_main` in `Main2Activity` and `R.layout.activity_main2` in MainActivity  may there is NullPointeException

Comment: Please post logcat error